# deleting an item from a list of lists in python using 'del'

Tags: python-2.7

```
del rec[1][1]
```

Is this the way to delete an item from a list of lists???

```
[ ['a','b','c'],
['d','e','f'],
['g','h','i'] ]
```

I want to delete b, e and h. How should I do that???

Comment: have a look at `numpy.delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove 'b', 'e' and 'h' by doing this

```
# the main list of lists
list1 = [ ['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'],['g','h','i'] ]

for x in xrange(len(list1)):
    del_list = list1[x][1]
    while del_list in list1[x]: list1[x].remove(del_list)
print((list1))
```

Output

```
[['a', 'c'], ['d', 'f'], ['g', 'i']]
```

This was easy since the entries were exactly at the 2nd positions of the sublists of list1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.pop(i)`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_pop.htm) method, where 'i' is an iterator.

```
rec = [ ['a','b','c'],
      ['d','e','f'],
      ['g','h','i'] ]

for i in range (0, len(rec)):
    print rec[i].pop(1)
```

Note that `.pop()` method also returns that item. 
The above code will result in :

```
b
e
h
```